# why is my character looking the wrong way?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

It worked before I added animation rigging (I used Root transform Rotation Offset)
now whatever I do it won't look in the right direction.

Comment: More details would be helpful

Comment: after I put animation rigging on the spine, my character just started looking the wrong way. when I offset the Root Transform Rotation it just rotates the legs. I've googled this problem alot and I heven't found a solution.

Comment: Can you try offsetting the root transform of the whole thing? I am not an animation specialist

Comment: how do I do that? I tried to offset the root transform rotation but it just rotates the legs

Comment: All of the root transforms? Are there any that control the top part. There must be.

Comment: I tried all of them. root position XZ, root position Y and root transform rotation.

Comment: sorry but I do nit know animation thtat well, so I can't help you too much.

Comment: don't worry, I fiddled with the multi aim constraint settings so it works now

Comment: good. you should post an answer or close the question so we know it is solved

Answer (score 1):

ok. the answer is if you go onto the settings in the multi aim constraint you can offset the direction the charecter is looking in. i used it to fix my problem